# What is the best VIEWs abbreviation in SQL codes?

Tags: sql, view, abbreviation

We use some abbreviations while we are writing our SQL codes like:

> db -> database
>     tbl -> table
>      sp -> stored procedure

What is the best abbreviation for `VIEW` in SQL ?

Comment: Please put your reason of down-vote

Comment: The down vote is because your not referring to any standard, so there is no answer to your question. Call it whatever you/your developers want.

Comment: `VIEW` is `VIEW` everywhere. SQL Server, MySQL, etc.

Comment: It's usually best to avoid using any such abbreviations - with the notable exception of tables and views, I'm struggling to think of any piece of SQL where you cannot tell the type of an object by its position in the statement. (And you shouldn't want to distinguish tables and views - they ought to be thought of as identical and interchangable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just

```
vw                //View
udf              //UserDefineFunction
```

Regards